# Select com YEAR e MONTH juntos

Tags: mysql

Bom é possível juntos o ano e o mês, e passar um paramento assim `20017-06` para o select?

```
SELECT SUM(valor) FROM contas where YEAR(data) = '2017' and MONTH(data) = '06'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível, use a função `date_format()` passando o formato desejado no lugar das duas funções.  `Y` para o ano com 4 dígitos e `m` para o mês com dois dígitos.

```
SELECT SUM(valor) FROM contas where date_format(data, '%Y-%m') = '2017-07'
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que estava precisando aqui. Vlw brother.

Comment: opa, vlw. isso vai ajudar bastante.